# Get text from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the text:

```
$("#id td div")[1].text();
```

But it return:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

When I try without text:

```
$("#id td div")[1];
```

It return the div... without error...

```
<div>$ 1000.00</div>
```

How can I get the text ?
$ 1000.00

Thanks!

Comment: can u post the structure..???

Comment: Better yet, JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$($("#id td div")[1]).text();
```

`[1]` returns you plain DOM object. You have to wrap it with jQuery again to use `.text()` jQuery function.

Otherwise you can use:

```
$("#id td div")[1].innerHTML;
```

or:

```
$("#id td div:eq(1)").text();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying: $(("#id td div")[1]).text(); rsrsrs... but $($("#id td div")[1]).text(); works for me! thanks!

Comment: `$.fn.text()` is equivalent to `element.textContent`, not `element.innerHTML`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: .... wait a minute, why would you use jQuery to select a node only to change it to a jQuery object again. If you trying to select by an index just use "eq()"

Comment: Yes, I can use eq(1)... same result. Thanks!

Comment: Same result... better performance as well as a lot more logical.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the text.

```
$("#tdCartoesCheques td div").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object is an array of DOM elements, which means when you access the array by index, you get a DOM element and not a jQuery object. For this purpose, jQuery has the `:eq()` selector:

```
$("#tdCartoesCheques td div:eq(1)").text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

As an alternative, this would also work, but is a bit more verbose and probably slower:

```
$($("#tdCartoesCheques td div")[1]).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tdCartoesCheques td div:eq(*the index*)").text();
```

index starts form 0.